# Rails post method ArgumentError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, integration-testing

I have the following code as part of an integration test that issues a `post` request.

```rb
assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
      post users_path, params: { user: {
        name: '',
        email: 'user@invalid',
        password: 'foo',
        password_confirmation: 'bar'
      }} 
    end
```

However, when running the tests, I keep getting the error:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
```

Upon inspecting the stack trace, I have realised that this error stems from the following `post` method in the following `integration.rb` file, which can be found at https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8015c2c2cf5c8718449677570f372ceb01318a32/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb

This method is defined as:

```rb
# Performs a POST request with the given parameters. See ActionDispatch::Integration::Session#process
      # for more details.
      def post(path, **args)
        process(:post, path, **args)
      end
```

As shown above, the `integration.rb` `post` method expects the `params` argument as a keyword argument, where the double-splat operator is used to transform the keyword argument into a hash. However, although I specify `params` as a keyword argument i.e.

```rb
post users_path, params: { user: {
        name: '',
        email: 'user@invalid',
        password: 'foo',
        password_confirmation: 'bar'
      }}
```

it seems that it is implicitly converted into a hash, thus causing the above error to be raised.

To confirm this, I modified the `integration.rb` `post` method to the following:

```rb
# Performs a POST request with the given parameters. See ActionDispatch::Integration::Session#process
      # for more details.
      def post(path, args)
        process(:post, path, **args)
      end
```

After making this change, the code runs perfectly.

My question is what am I missing? Is Rails performing some sort of implicit conversion of the `params` keyword argument to a hash?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have since solved the problem.

The problem stemmed from not including the latest version of `rails-controller-testing` gem. After updating the gem, the code works.